# Allure Test NG report TestBody is missing

Tags: maven, automated-tests, cucumber, testng, allure

I am facing this weird issue that my allure testNg report does not show Test body section. This is my maven command

```
mvn clean test 
-DisBrowserStack=true 
-DdeviceFlavors="Google Nexus6" 
-DdeviceOsFlavors="6.0" 
-Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles="testng.xml"
```

This is my pom File : also I have attached the report screenshot the issue is it does not include TestBody segment.

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    cucumber.framework
    cucumber.framework
    1.0
    jar

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <mavencompiler.version>3.6.0</mavencompiler.version>
    <mavensurefire.version>2.21.0</mavensurefire.version>
    <cucumber.version>4.3.1</cucumber.version>
    <appium.version>7.0.0</appium.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.9.4</aspectj.version>
    <allure.version>2.12.0</allure.version>
    <jetty.version>9.2.10.v20150310</jetty.version>
    <jackson.version>2.9.0</jackson.version>
    <httpclient.version>1.22.0</httpclient.version>
    <okhttp.version>3.11.0</okhttp.version>
    <json.version>20170516</json.version>
    <hamcrest.version>1.3</hamcrest.version>
    <springjdbc.version>5.1.3.RELEASE</springjdbc.version>
    <postgresql.version>42.1.4</postgresql.version>
    <jaxb.version>2.3.0</jaxb.version>
    <javaxactivation.version>1.1.1</javaxactivation.version>
     <cucumbertestng.version>4.3.1</cucumbertestng.version>
    <testng.version>6.14.3</testng.version>




</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${mavencompiler.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${mavensurefire.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/${TEST_NAME}RunnerTest.java</include>
                </includes>
                <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"

                </argLine>
                <properties>

                </properties>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <webAppSourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site/allure-maven-plugin</webAppSourceDirectory>
                <stopKey>stop</stopKey>
                <stopPort>1234</stopPort>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>${appium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
        <version>${httpclient.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>${okhttp.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>${json.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-cucumber4-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.version}</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${springjdbc.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jaxb.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jaxb.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${jaxb.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>${javaxactivation.version}</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- All Test NG stuff-->

             <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                <version>${testng.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
                <version>${cucumbertestng.version}</version>
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
                <version>${allure.version}</version>
            </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

[image]

This is the Cucumber runner file

```
package cucumber.mobile;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import device.Device;
import device.DeviceFactory;






@CucumberOptions(plugin = { "pretty", "json:target/cucumber-report.json","junit:TEST-all.xml",
        "html:target/html/"},  features = "src/test/resources/features/SignUp.feature" ,glue = { "steps" }, tags = { "@Mobile" })
public class ParallelRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    @BeforeTest
    @Parameters({ "deviceName", "platformVersion" })
    public void executeParallelTests(String deviceName, String platformVersion) {

        Device device = new Device();
        device.setDeviceName(deviceName);
        device.setOsVersion(platformVersion);
        DeviceFactory.setDevice(device);

    }

}
```

Comment: anybody knows how to fix this?

Comment: hmm . seems like a bug in the allure-testng  I found this I am not sure what's the status of this issue.It was hanging there for a while now.  https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-java/issues/301

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this issue with allure-testng v.2.17.0 and TestNG v.7.5.0

The only thing that helped me was downgrading TestNG to 7.4.0 after which the test bodies started showing as they should.

So try playing around with allure-testng and testng versions to find the compatible combination